# How to make Windows 11's new auto-hiding scrollbar thicker?

Tags: windows-11, uwp

I want to make the scrollbars thicker. I have followed this tutorial ( https://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-8-scroll-bar-hard-see-change-windows-8-scrollbar-width ) but I think it only affects the traditional, non-disappearing scrollbar, like that of File Explorer. The scrollbar width of new (probably UWP) apps like Notepad remains the same. Is there a separate setting for new apps?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in many places; that might be why no one answered it here.

Windows 11 Always show scrollbars:

•  "Always show scrollbars" does not mean what it says.

•  It doesn't mean show scrollbars "always".  When there is nothing to scroll, scrollbars are not shown, regardless of this setting.
•  It doesn't "show scrollbars" that would otherwise be hidden.  Scrollbars are already always shown (when there is something to scroll); they are just smaller.

•  What this option really does is suppress the annoying, distracting, disgusting, embarrassing shriveling of "inactive" scrollbars until you hover over them, and then they swell.
•  This option should really be called "Don't shrivel the scrollbars".

•  There is more than one way to get to this setting:
•Windows+I (System [settings]:  Accessibility > Visual effects:  Always show scrollbars (click to switch it on)
•  or
•Start button, then start typing "scr..." or "alw..." and then click on Always show scroll bars  (Yes, they added a space; they can't spell their own setting the same way twice.)  Then Always show scrollbars (click to switch it on).

•  (In Windows 10, this was called "Automatically hide scrollbars in Windows".  They are never actually hidden, just made narrower.  Naturally they renamed this option and reversed it meaning, just to confuse people.)

•  This is in a key under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility.  DynamicScrollbars = 0 means don't shrink; = 1 means shrink.

•  You can change width of the scrollbar at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics. ScrollHeight and ScrollWidth.

•  One help page warns:  "This will not affect the size of scrollbars used in Microsoft Store apps and any modern UI like Settings or Start menu.  Some third party apps may use their own scrollbar size instead."